# How to store a text field value and retrieve it later - Selenium Web Driver Using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Need your help in Selenium Webdriver coding with Java.

I have a scenario, where I create a Course name and submit it to the database and then later I need to search for the Course by the name I created it.
Simply the work flow would be;
1. Type the course name in text box (Here I'm randomly generating a string so it's not hard coded, I need to retrieve exactly what I typed here)
2. Store the typed name
3. In the search box type that name

```
private void createCurriculum() throws InterruptedException {
    selenium.open("http://url.com");

    driver.findElement(By.id("Text1")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Text1")).sendKeys("My Curriculum" + genData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(10)); // Here I'm randomly generating the name, I need to retrieve what I type here in the next method
    //String curName = driver.findElement(By.id("Text1")).getAttribute("value"); 
    //I tried this but it didn't work

    Thread.sleep(300);
}



private void searchCurriculum(String curName) throws InterruptedException {
    selenium.open("http://url.com");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/input")).sendKeys("curName"); // Here I want to retireve what I previously generated. It's not working
    // . . .
```

Additionally in the main method, I have declared the variable too.

```
public class TestCaseCreateCurriculum {
   private Selenium selenium;
   private WebDriver driver;
   GenerateData genData;

   public String curName;
   // . . .
```

Could anybody help me to correct this code?

> This perfectly worked after modifying (thanks to Vageesh Bhasin)

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Text1")).sendKeys(curName = "My Curriculum" + genData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(10));
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/input")).sendKeys(curName);
```

Comment: Why don;t you store the course name in a variable? String curName = "My Curriculum" + genData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(10); Use this inside your sendkeys call.

Comment: What exactly is the error and @ which line?

Comment: If you are using `curName` variable as String, then why are you passing it as string again in `sendKeys()`

Comment: @Vageesh Bhasin: thanks heaps yaar.. with few modifications it perfectly worked!!

driver.findElement(By.id("Text1")).sendKeys(curName = "My Curriculum" + genData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(10));

And in the second method used
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/input")).sendKeys(curName);

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like:

```
String course = "My Curriculum" + genData.generateRandomAlphaNumeric(10);
driver.findElement(By.id("Text1")).sendKeys(course);
```

> Later you can use stored variable anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the value in a class as an attribute, if it not solve your problem you can serialize the value to restore when you want.